# If you are doing a replication study using the same instrument, can you statistically compare the results of the two studies

Tags: t-test

Scores on the Sexual Attitudes and Beliefs Survey in this sample will be significantly higher, indicating less comfort, than scores in the published national sample collected by Tennille et al. (2022).

Comment: I think we need more detail here about what you think the problem is with comparing them as to their location.